# When does BroadcastReceiver get enabled?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I register a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest of my app (e.g to be notified of network changes), when does it start to be notified ? At device startup ? Or does the app need to be manually launched ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It starts receiving broadcasts when your device is booted completely. However, starting from Honeycomb (API Level 12), you need to launch your application at least once to make it enable for start listening broadcasts.

In Honeycomb and above, when you install your application, the framework marks it as **STOPPED_PACKAGE** and does not include its broadcast receivers for listening. But once you launch your application once, such marking is removed and you are good to go :)

As an alternate, try setting the flag `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` to your broadcast intent in order to include those packages too which are stopped.

For example:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: if I start the app once then reboot the device, the broadcast receiver will be enabled at startup, right?

Comment: you can always use Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES (regardless of min-sdk) because it's static final; it's value is inlined compile time.